# Using the Cauchy integral formula to evaluate $\int_{\gamma=(a,a)} \frac{z}{z^4-1} dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I'm trying to understand how to use the Cauchy integral formula, but a bit confused as to how to use it as I cant seem to get the right answer!

> $$\int_{\gamma=(a,a)} \frac{z}{z^4-1} dz$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ and $a\not= 1/2$.

please note: this must be solved using cauchy integral formula!

Comment: @sarah Let me know if my edit has transcribed the question properly.  I don't know what you mean by $w=a$ and $r=a$ - what are $w$ and $r$?

Comment: is there any way of moving this question up to the top again as no one seems to have answered it?

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$f(z)=\dfrac{z}{z^4-1}$ has poles at $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$. There are two cases:

1. When $0<a<1/2$, the circle with center $a$ and radius $a$ does not enclose any poles of $f$. Hence $\int_{\gamma(a,a)}f(z)\,dz=0$.
2. When $a>1/2$, the circle with center $a$ and radius $a$ encloses two poles of $f$, namely $1$ and $i$. The quickest way to evaluate the integral would be the residue theorem. But if we are allowed only the Cauchy integral formula, the partial fraction decomposition can be used:
   $$\dfrac{z}{z^4-1} = \frac{z}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1} +\frac{i}{z-i}-\frac{i}{z+i}\right) $$
   By the Cauchy integral formula,
   $$\int_{\gamma(a,a)}\frac{z}{4} \frac{1}{z-1}\,dz=2\pi i \frac14 $$ and $$\int_{\gamma(a,a)}\frac{z}{4} \frac{i}{z-i}\,dz=2\pi i \frac{i^2}4 $$ while the other two integrals are zero.

Comment: The circle with center $a$ and radius $a$ does not contain the singularity at $z=i$.