# How to apply the cauchy theorem to evaluate an integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

can someone please explain/show me how to apply the cauchy interal formula?

Here is a question:

> $$\int_{\gamma=(a,a)} \frac{z}{z^4-1} dz$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>0$ and $a\not= 1/2$.

So im guessing we use the standard simple cauchy formula and split the fraction into partial fractions? Is this correct and how do i do this in regards to an integral?

Comment: Same question as [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330534/using-the-cauchy-integral-formula-to-evaluate-int-gamma-a-a-fraczz4)

Comment: it didnt get answered though, and the rules say you can ask a duplicate question if no answer or no correct answer was given, which in this case is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Again, its the same trick.
When $a<1/2$, the function is analytic in the whole domain, by Cauchy Theorem, the integral is $0$!

When $a>1/2$. since there is only one singularity in the domain, which is $z=1$, apply the Cauchy Integral formula, we get
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z}{z^4-1}=2\pi ig(1) \text{ where }g(z)=\frac{z}{z^3+z^2+z+1}.$$
Therefore, the final answer is $\cfrac{\pi i}{2}$.

Comment: wow thank you!the a's were confusing me before i didnt know what to do with them! Thank you.